# Como consumir função de validação?

Tags: php

Por motivos didáticos, criei uma função em `php` para validar 3 campos, a função está no arquivo `validate.php` :

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Jorge
 * Date: 01/06/2018
 * Time: 10:40
 */


function valida($nome, $senha, $email) {

$error = [
        'nome' => 'Não é permitido caracteres especiais nem espaços em branco!',
        'senha' => 'Não é permitido caracteres especiais nem espaços em branco!',
        'email' => 'E-mail incorreto'
       ];
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $nome)) {
    $error["nome"];
    exit;
}

if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $senha)) {
    $error["senha"];
    exit;
}

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error["email"];
    exit;
}

 return $error;
}
```

No meu controller estou usando-a da seguinte maneira, mas sei que não está correto:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Jorge
 * Date: 30/05/2018
 * Time: 17:36
 */

require "../models/Connection.php";
require "validate.php";

$errorNome = '';
$errorSenha = '';
$errorEmail = '';
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $user = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $pass = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    if (valida($user, $pass, $email)) {
       $errorNome = $error["nome"];
       $errorPass = $error["senha"];
       $errorEmail = $error["email"];
       header("location: ../views/add.php");
    }
    else {

    $pdo = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (nome, email, senha) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $pdo->bindParam(1, $user);
        $pdo->bindParam(2, $email);
        $pdo->bindParam(3, $pass);
        $pdo->execute();

        if ($pdo->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo "sucesso!";
        }
    }
}
```

Na `view` está da seguinte maneira:

```
 require "../controllers/addUserController.php";
?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="../controllers/addUserController.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"> <span> <?=$errorNome?> </span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email"> <span> <?=$errorEmail?> </span>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"> <span> <?=$errorSenha?> </span>
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Minha dúvida é, como faço pra permitir a inserção no banco apenas se estiver tudo correto conforme definido na função? E caso algum campo estiver errado, como faço pra mostrar a mensagem de erro?

Essa é maneira correta de realizar uma verificação? Caso não, qual seria uma boa opção?

Agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: Esse exemplo mostrado funciona (chega a mostrar as mensagens de erro)?

Comment: @Juven_v não, não é exibida.

Answer (score 2):

Algumas adaptações são necessárias para o seu exemplo funcionar da maneira que está organizado. Primeiro a sua função `valida()` deveria retornar coisas diferentes, caso haja ou não erros, um exemplo seria:

validade.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @return string|null caso haja algum erro de validação retorna
 * um array de strings descrevendo os erros 
 * é retornado, caso não haja erros de validação, retorna null;
 * 
*/
function valida($nome, $senha, $email) {

    $error = [
            'nome' => 'Não é permitido caracteres especiais nem espaços em branco!',
            'senha' => 'Não é permitido caracteres especiais nem espaços em branco!',
            'email' => 'E-mail incorreto'
           ];

    $errosEncontrados = [];

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $nome)) {
        $errosEncontrados['nome'] = $error["nome"];
    }

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $senha)) {
        $errosEncontrados['nome'] = $error["senha"];
    }

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errosEncontrados['nome'] = $error["email"];
    }

    //verifica o tamanho do vetor $errosEncontrados
    if(count($errosEncontrados) > 0){
        return $errosEncontrados;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Com essas alterações na função valida é possivel verificar no controller se os campos passaram na validação ou não. No controller você precisa fazer algumas alterações (nos comentarios tem mais detalhes):

em seu controller.php

```
<?php
//......
$pass = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    //vetor com os erros retornados pela função valida
    //ou null caso não existam
    $erros = valida($user, $pass, $email);
    if ($erros !== null) {
       $errorNome = $errors["nome"];
       $errorPass = $errors["senha"];
       $errorEmail = $errors["email"];
       //se você fizem um header location, essas variaveis não existiram 
       //mais na nova requisição.
       //header("location: ../views/add.php");

       //é mais adequado usar um require ou include, nesse caso
       //nada mais deveria ser impresso, além do que está dentro de add.php
       require '../views/add.php';
       //então faça um exite para garantir que apenas o conteudo do 
       //arquivo incluido seja retorndado para o navegador
       exit;
    }
    else {

    $pdo = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (nome, email, senha) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $pdo->bindParam(1, $user);
        $pdo->bindParam(2, $email);
        $pdo->bindParam(3, $pass);
        $pdo->execute();
//.......
```

Aqui houve apenas duas alterações, uma para checar se há erros de validação, e a outra relacionado ao header location, que não funcionaria como o esperado.

Na sua view deve funcionar como esperado, a menos que o arquivo `add.php` seja chamado sem que as variaveis nele utilizadas tenham sido declaradas antes. Para evitar esse possivel problema, basta alterar as ocorrências de `<?=$errorEmail?>` por .

Uma alternativa seria você usar alguma biblioteca de validação, como o [respect](https://github.com/Respect/Validation)

Comment: No lugar de `$errors` não deveria ser `$errosEncontrados`?  Ou é isso msm?

Comment: `$errosEncontrados`  só visivel dentro da função valida(), questão de escopo. O valor retornado pela função valida é que é armazenado na variavel `$erros`, e é visivel no controller.